# methods not giving wanted result?

Tags: java, graphics, awt

I have this program that is supposed to "`draw`" Mickey Mouse face :

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Mickey extends Canvas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Canvas canvas = new Mickey();
        canvas.setSize(900, 500);    

        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void mickey(Graphics g) {
        Rectangle bb = new Rectangle(400, 400, 100, 100);
        boxOval(g, bb);

        int dx = bb.width/2;
        int dy = bb.height/2;

        Rectangle half = new Rectangle(bb.x, bb.y, dx, dy);

        half.translate(-dx/2, -dy/2);
        boxOval(g, half);

        half.translate(dx*2, 0);
        boxOval(g, half);
    }
    public void boxOval(Graphics g, Rectangle bb) {
        g.fillOval(bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height);
    }    
}
```

The program just shows nothing and is blank, is there something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to override the [`paint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html#paint-java.awt.Graphics-) method as described in the javadoc

> An application must subclass the `Canvas` class in order to get useful
>   functionality such as creating a custom component. The `paint` method
>   **must be overridden in order to perform custom graphics** on the canvas.

So here simply try to rename your method `public void mickey(Graphics g)` to `public void paint(Graphics g)`.